# What's the sound of wolf's footsteps called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to write a paragraph and I need to describe the sound that a wolf's  paws/footsteps will make whilst running.
Can anyone recommend me a word?

Comment: Running on what?

Comment: Give an example sentence, and you're likely to get more productive suggestions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suggest **"padding"** on the sand, on the gravel, or **"thudding"**.

> - [**pad**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pad) - (verb)  to walk so that one's footsteps make a dull, muffled sound.

I could hear the wolf's paws padding on the sand.

The sound of heavy paws padding on the stairs.

I could hear the wolf's paws padding across the soft ground.

or

> - [**thud**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/thud) - (verb) "to make a heavy, dull sound"

She heard the wolf's paws thudding against the ground and she strained herself to run faster.

I could hear the wolf's paws thudding against the ground close behind me.

Comment: thank you, I think the thud makes sense!

Comment: @ova: No, I don't think a wolf's paws can't thud. Only a heavy object can thud. They can pad, but not if they are running fast.

Comment: Now I hope those poor people are able to escape from the wolves! :)

Comment: "Pad" is good, "thud" doesn't fit well to me. Wolves are light and agile, they're not being chased by rhinos!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there's a word that specifically describes the sound of wolves feet colliding with the ground. Maybe you're looking for **thump** or **thumping**?

Here's a word that may be useful in describing the sound. Although this word is usually associated with horses, you can use it for other four-legged animals:

### gallop

> a fast gait of the horse or other quadruped in which, in the course of each stride, all four feet are off the ground at once.
>
> <sup>source: [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gallop)</sup>

*"I knew the wolves were getting closer as their galloping was getting louder and louder."*

A couple of wolf-related websites say that "gallop" is an appropriate term in this context.

[Alderleaf Wilderness College: Wold Tracks & Sign](https://www.wildernesscollege.com/wolf-tracks.html)

> **Gaits:** Wolves are built to travel long distances. They most often travel in a trot (equivalent to a human jog), either a side trot or a direct register trot. Wolves can also walk, lope and gallop. They will use different gaits according to their needs.

[Wolf Country](http://www.wolfcountry.net/information/WolfObserved.html)

> Wolves walk, trot, lope, or gallop. Their legs are long, and they walk at about 4 miles (6.4 kilometers) per hour, but can reach speeds of 35 mph during a chase. Their usual mode of travel is to trot, which they do at various speeds, generally between 8 to 10 miles (12.8 to 16 kilometers) per hour.

Also see a list of potentially useful terms on this Wikipedia page: [Canine gait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canine_gait)